# self patching primary key in MySQL, I can do it but how do I case id=1

Tags: mysql, primary-key, subquery

for reasons I'd rather not go into I have a "self a patching" pkey id requirement for a table. what I mean is the new insert id must always be the lowest id possible, and the table is deliberately left without `auto_increment`

this is what I have so far

```
INSERT INTO thefile (
  file_id,
  fullpathname,
  filesize    
 ) VALUES (
    (SELECT MIN(t1.file_id+1) FROM thefile t1 LEFT JOIN thefile t2 ON t1.file_id + 1 = t2.file_id WHERE t2.file_id IS NULL),
    '/some/path/file',
    24576
  );
```

the idea is that it fills up the db and always tries to use the lowest available id (i.e. as time progresses, lets say `row file_id=3` gets removed: it will immediately insert the next row at `file_id=3` - - there are reasons why referential integrity is not relevant)

now it works brilliantly except that it doesn't work on `thefile` table if `thefile` has zero rows, or `thefile count(*)` = zero

processing overhead is VERY important for me here: what's the lowest processing overhead for always guaranteeing that `file_id` will be 1 if `count=0`

Comment: coalesce is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *... it works brilliantly except that it doesn't work on thefile table if thefile has zero rows, or `thefile` count(*) = zero*

**Change**:

```
SELECT MIN(t1.file_id+1) 
FROM thefile t1 
LEFT JOIN thefile t2 
  ON t1.file_id + 1 = t2.file_id 
WHERE t2.file_id IS NULL),
```

**To**:

```
SELECT coalesce( MIN( t1.file_id ), 0 ) + 1 
FROM thefile t1 
LEFT JOIN thefile t2 
  ON t1.file_id + 1 = t2.file_id 
WHERE t2.file_id IS NULL),
```

Comment: thank you everyone, perfect answers, I'd forgotten about COALESCE!

Answer (score 0):

use of coalesce seems appropriate here.

```
MIN(coalesce(t1.file_id,0)+1)
```

or in full:

```
INSERT INTO thefile (
  file_id,
  fullpathname,
  filesize    
 ) VALUES (
    (SELECT MIN(coalesce(t1.file_id,0)+1) 
     FROM thefile t1 
     LEFT JOIN thefile t2 
       ON coalesce(t1.file_id,0) + 1 = t2.file_id 
     WHERE t2.file_id IS NULL),
    '/some/path/file',
    24576
  );
```

This assumes you don't start at 0 too...  otherwise the coalesce would need to be -1.